# What is the best way to create an eye-catching display of numeric values in a web page?

Tags: info-visualisation, typography, data, dashboard

I am going to design a management level monitoring page for displaying some sums and counts. No interaction is allowed and it will be used as a monitoring page on a big LCD in the managers view. The project is a web-based application using jQuery. I am looking for some idea to design this page. The amounts are not suitable for charts or guages. But I don't want to display them as raw text and some kind of graphics for making it eye-catching is intended.

What is the best way to create an eye-catching display of numeric values in a web page?

Comment: This isn't the right place for this kind of requests. Voted to close.

Comment: If text, charts and gauges are no good you are left with indicating data in other ways using perhaps size, color, time and location, but agree this is the wrong place for this question. Although Graphic Design SE will probably be more appropriate, I also suggest you provide some examples and an idea of how much data is involved, how the data may change and what is important for your managers to ascertain from a quick glance at the screen. I hesitated to vote for closing because I feel great data visualisation makes for a better user experience...

Comment: I think it's an OK UX question, though probably suited to GD as typically dashboard apps for exec's are really more about eye candy than anything.

Comment: When I asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760921/idea-for-eye-catching-display-of-numeric-values-in-a-web-page) in stackoverflow.com, they asked me to move it here. I am completely confused where is the right place for asking this question.

Comment: @Roger Attrill: I mean I prefer not to use raw text with html formats. I am looking for some graphical solution which renders an image or canvas tag in a fantasy way.

Comment: This question is really about typography, color, sizing and how it relates to conversion (in this case, conversion means interpreting the information easily at a glance and acting on it). I think it's a valid design question for both UX and GD. Let's keep it here and see what kind of answers show up; if we don't get anything valuable we can move it to GD and see if they have something to add.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the nature of data, you can use [Tufte's Sparklines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte#Sparkline). This approach combines text, color and small graphics. Google Analytics makes use of this approach in their control panel:

[image]

Comment: +1 Tufte is definitely the man to read up on for this type of stuff.

Comment: Here is a link to check out Edward Tufte's books. He is the god of data visualization. http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi

Comment: Tufte only invented the term, the actual design was done by Peter Zelchenko: http://pete.zelchenko.com/portfolio/screen/2gk.htm

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Ducksboard](http://ducksboard.com/), an online service that you can use to monitor information coming from other web services like Mailchimp, Twitter, Zendesk, etc. They have some good inspiration regarding how to display various kinds of information graphically using graphs, large numerical readouts, sparklines, and specific data formats like weather, time, etc.

You can [try a demo here](https://demo.ducksboard.com/demo/).

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach is a big number, with it's meaning in smaller text below. If it's sums you could work out a flow-chart that joins the values into sums. Counts sounds like it could work with gauges but you'd need a max value. Otherwise you could use "sticks", where you cross over the fifth one as you do on paper. It depends if a high value is good or bad. They also work great with other visualisations, like Tufte's Sparklines mentioned in Pau Giner's answer.

StackExchange uses this next to the questions on listings, with "X votes" and "Y answers":

[image]

I've used this on a [simple ReadItLater stats site](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5566693/DB%20Sites/ReadItLater/index.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response. In fact I am looking for a graphical text solution, not pure text. For example, [this (an rgraph sample)](http://www.rgraph.net/examples/led.html) is a good starting point. But it's not as cool as what I want.

Comment: I see. I find the big number in a good font and nice color to be aestheticly pleasing. You can also use them with other things, such as Tufte's sparklines as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

How about something that repeatedly morphs the text between the label and the value, that could be styled however you like in terms of size, colors, line thicknesses and fills.

For example, you can do this using (the fantastic) Raphael.js - see the [text morphing demo](http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html) - just type in a series of letters or numbers and the shape morphs between each character. It should be sufficiently 'eye-catching'.